# Final boss impasse

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

The Rebel Flagship has his hacking drone locked onto my weapons, and it seems to have re-routed full power to Hacking and Cloak. Between them, I'm just barely able to squeeze off a shot of my Dual Laser, but my Fire Bombs and Flak II... can't even get close to charged. The Flagship's weapons are down (except the laser one, since it's harmless), so... I'm stuck!

What do?

Comment: Hack their shields then shoot out their hacking control room? It'll buy you some time.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm sadly short on Systems... I'm running the cloaker freak and was only able to pick up Shields.

Comment: Maybe tell us what systems you have? Do you have hacking, teleporter, etc?

Comment: @Dycker Sorry, I didn't have anything useful - no hacking, no mind control, no drones, no teleporter... it was a terrible run, but I did unlock the Crystal Cruiser this time so that's cool!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming you don't have any viable counter-attack plan with your current setup, you might want to consider retreating.

In the advanced edition the flagship has to occupy the "base" for 3 consecutive turns before you lose.  If you can visit a shop and trade a weapon for another that might do the trick.  More likely there are some encounter beacons you haven't completed or allowed the rebels to capture.  These will give scrap.

The best option, however, is reaching a repair station which in the advanced edition will give you scrap in addition to other benefits.  If you truly will reach a deadlock, you'll need to use some extra scrap to change your loadout.

Oh, and the best part about retreating? **They'll have to hack all over again, and they might choose your sensors next time!**

Comment: ... How the hell did you call that? I followed the Flagship to its next jump, and sure enough, WHAM, Hacker on the sensors!

Comment: Even a broken clock is right twice a day?

Comment: After that, victory was a piece of cake. Except at one point where my luck failed me and half my ship caught fire XD No shields, half weapons, and a crazy Mantis PLUS four human boarders... Yet somehow I pulled through with no casualties!

Comment: Excellent work. I'm glad to hear I could help.